# Ajax.ActionLink Alternative - Net Core

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

Earlier in *MVC* I used `@Ajax.ActionLink` for Ajax call and replaced container in my layout.

Now in *.Net Core* there is anything like *AjaxHelper* back then.

How can I form *Ajax* call without writing *jquery* script for every menu item in my dashboard.

I tried `@Url.Action` with anonymous *Ajax* parameters but that won't work.

```
@Url.Action("Index", "User", new
{
  data_ajax = "true",
  data_ajax_method = "GET",
  data_ajax_mode = "replace",
  data_ajax_update = "#replace"
}))"
```

Comment: Do you miss js packages? Check the reference to jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax scripts package https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: I installed it via nuget, it didn't added any .js file to the wwwroot/js, Jquery Ajax works great.

Answer (score 1):

No. Honestly, you never needed it anyways. All it did was create a regular link and then add a trivial bit of JavaScript you can easily add yourself. Long and short, let it go:

```
<a class="menu-item" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="User">Click Me</a>
```

Then:

```
<script>
    $('.menu-item').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, function (html) {
            $('#replace').html(html);
        });
    });
</script>
```

By binding to the class, you only need this one piece of JS for any link with a `menu-item` class.